# Ionic Cannot find name 'require' @types/node already installed

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

This code is working in my Angular project.  I had to install "@types/node": "^8.9.5" and add the type to my tsconfig to stop it throwing an error.

I am getting the same error in Ionic and it has "@types/node": "~12.6.6" installed by default.  It throws an error if I try to run "npm install @types/node".

The project runs I just can't build the project.

Error on compile:

```
ERROR in error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'node'.
src/app/pages/get-member-details/get-member-details.page.ts(63,37): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'require'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node`.
```

Code:

```
    import * as i18nIsoCountries from 'i18n-iso-countries';

    async ngOnInit() {
//THIS IS LINE 63 BELOW
        i18nIsoCountries.registerLocale(require('i18n-iso-countries/langs/en.json'));
        const indexedArray = i18nIsoCountries.getNames('en');
        for (const key in indexedArray) {
          const value = indexedArray[key];
          this.countries.push(value);
        }
      }
```

Comment: what do you trying to achive give more detail

Comment: Please share your file "get-member-details.page.ts". Seems Something is not right in this file.

Comment: I am loading a list of countries from 'i18n-iso-countries'.  The code works fine it is just giving me a type error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out under the node_modules folder the @types/node folder was empty.
It muse have messed up the install.  I had to delete the folder and reinstall.
It is now working.